# Manga about a dragon who is reincarnated as the child of the woman who killed him

Tags: story-identification, manga, dragons, reincarnation

The dragon fights with the heroes but does not kill them. One person (I think it was a woman) constantly comes to kill him, but then they become friends. After that, the woman catches one of his gaps and kills him. The dragon reincarnates as the child of the woman who killed him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: I don't remember 

Comment: What do you mean by "_the woman catches one of his gaps_"?